# create field in typescript intellij 14.1.2 ultimate from usage

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript

Coming from Eclipse, I like to use a field first (for example) this.fieldname = "value", and then quick fix (control-1) the field declaration into existence without having to type it myself.  It would create "private String fieldname;" for example in my class file.

In intellij I thought the same thing was possible across its editors, but I am not able to alt-enter or control space the field into existence.  How do I accomplish this?  This is for Typescript in Intellij Ultimate.  I have enabled the TypeScript compiler per the banner popup.

Comment: FWIW atom-typescript also has it : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript#quick-fix ;)

Comment: Can't seem to find it - seems so basic!  After like 10 hours theres already stuff I miss from eclipse, crazy.